# NGINX server on Debian not taking my config

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I have pointed my domain rohanpatra.ga to my server and installed nginx. I am currently running two domains on the server, rohanpatra.ga, and meetsecured.tk. MeetSecured is a blockchain video conferencing platform based on Jitsi Meet, and it seems to be running fine. But, when I go to rohanpatra.ga, it just goes to the default nginx page.

I've created the config file:

[sites-available directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz24O.png)
[config file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adQAw.png)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/rohanpatra.ga;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name your_domain;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And symlinked the file to the sites-enabled folder:

[sites-enabled directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WpEp.png)

Here is the root directory of the site and the content of the one file index.php:

[/var/www/rohanpatra.ga directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijY1I.png)

[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Lyf.png)

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

as requested:

```
root@debian-8gb-hel1-1:~# ps auxww |grep nginx
```

[reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pckdm.png)

```
root      5874  0.0  0.1  70944  9032 ?        Ss   May30   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  9129  0.0  0.1  71228  9516 ?        S    21:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  9130  0.0  0.0  71228  6344 ?        S    21:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  9131  0.0  0.0  71228  6344 ?        S    21:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  9132  0.0  0.0  71228  6344 ?        S    21:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     10356  0.0  0.0   6144   888 pts/0    S+   22:29   0:00 grep nginx
```

Comment: Could you post "ps auxww |grep nginx" as well?

Comment: @merinoff added to the question

Comment: Never post your code or config files as screenshots if you want your question to be answered.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for the advice, I added the text to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) you have misconfigured server_name parameter in your config.

Correct config should look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name rohanpatra.ga;

    root /var/www/rohanpatra.ga;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And be sure that this FQDN `rohanpatra.ga` is correctly resolving on the server itself.

You can check by typing: `nslookup rohanpatra.ga` at server console.